# How to access Model object in ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working with a WEB API application in ASP .NET Core 2.0 where I have a custom filter attribute that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`.

How can I access the Model object passed to a controller action in POST call, in `ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted()`

The mentioned method is passed a `ResultExecutedContext` object but I could not find an easy and reliable way to get Model object from it.

The filter I have, looks like the following:

```
public sealed class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        var model = ????????????? 
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

and the controller looks like the following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(MyCustomFilter))]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<MyModel> data)
    {
        // my logic to process model here. In my filter, I want to access data, which is passed into this Post method 

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I set a private var in the controller and assign the posted model to it on the controllers action

```
 private YourModel _yourModel;

 public ActionResult MyAction(YourModel model)
 {
      _yourModel = model;
       return View();
 }

 protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
 {
       //Access _yourModel here     
 }
```

To access the model from the filterContext parameter passed in, you can use the below

```
var model = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).ViewData.Model;
```

Try using TempData. Set tempdata to the model in your action.

```
 TempData["Model"] = myModel;
```

Then access using the TempData on the context.

```
var x = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).TempData["Model"];
```

Hope that's what you meant.
thanks

Comment: The filter is implemented in a separate class.

Comment: So you are overriding the OnResultExecuted Method in your own seperate class?

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer. You should be able to access the model that way. It works on mine although I do not have a separate class. Let me know if its ok or not... dont want to leave an answer posted that's of no help! :) thanks

Comment: The following line is giving null in  my case:   var model = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).ViewData.Model;

Comment: OK. Last attempt. Try setting Tempdata to your model, then access the TempData of the context. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Indeed. Be interested to hear if anyone sorts it for you.

Comment: If you can post your code of your executing context class along with how its used within the controller then I can try and recreate myself.

Comment: Well that code works fine for me. I do apologize though... i've only just noticed that your using .Net Core... I'm on MVC5. I take it when you debug the post method that the data attribute is not null?